# Javascript. What .input exactly does for array items?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some function that sorts string based on digits in the words. For example: `"a2m on5 Stac6koverflow q4uestion I1 askin3g"` becomes `"I1 a2m askin3g q4uestion on5 Stac6koverflow"`.

It looks like follows:

```
const order = string => {
  return string
         .split(' ')
         .map(item => item.match(/\d/))
         .sort()
         .map(item => item.input)
         .join(' ');
};
```

I understand the code, except for the `.map(item => item.input)` part. What exactly .input does for the array item here?

Thank you!

Comment: It map's the property called `input` on the `item` as the result.  So if you had `[{input: 1}, {input: 2}]`,  map would return `[1,2]`

Answer (score 3):

Look up what [item.match(/\d/)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) does.

Look at the details of [the return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value):

> `input`: A copy of the search string.

Answer (score 0):

`item.input` is accessing the `input` key of the `item` object and it's not a method.
`map(item => item.input)` return a new array which consists of only the value within `.input` for each item in the array